# An error occured during export, Codesign failed , XCode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, archive, ipa

[image: Xcode8.2.1 archiving screeshot]

AnyOne has an idea how to solve this ?
PS : My project Settings are all verified.
Thanks.

Comment: please google it, i am sure you will find plenty of possibilities.

Comment: if i posted it here, that means i have already tried all solutions that i've searched on google.

Comment: Make sure that all profiles in system is up-to-date as developer site.
Check bundle ID is connected with profile.

Comment: already checked

Comment: Did you tried by Setting Coding signing in Automatic mode while exporting?

Comment: yes , already tried it but same error

Comment: have you used cocoapods?

Comment: not in this project.

Comment: I was having the same problem, I took 2-3 days to find the solution, I was using Alamofire and other SDK not via cocoapod, later I added cocoapod and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open finder--> press option Go - > Go to Folder

type your project path in that like :

```
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourprojectname/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
```

Now new window opens with list of Files, There you see `yourApp.app` file.

Now,

2. Open Terminal and type just `cd` then just drag `yourApp.app` (from finder window) to terminal, now you will get the path for the app, now press enter.
3. Now type command below:

> xattr -rc .

Don't forget "."(Dot) at last.

Press enter button.

Now, Go to your Xcode project and clean and run again.

**EDIT:**

it is all about path miss match and cached path that you used before. so while doing above steps you are clearing build path for the project, that will make xcode project to run as new without taking cache.

making copy of the project and running same project with xcode make issue or keeping project in icloud and running from that location also makes issue.

May this help.

Comment: what will happen by this code / method? i mean internal working?

Answer (score 0):

i just changed codeSign -> Release to  iOS distribution then i put it back to iOS developer then i did a simple clean.
And that solved my problem (find it quite strange !!!).